# xsl:for-each loop is not working with xmi files

Tags: xml, xslt, xmi

I want to generate new xmi file using xslt but I'm having a problem with the xsl:for-each loop when reading the name of the tags I think because it works fine with simple xml tags but when using xmi tag (uml:package for example) I got no result.
Here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<XMI xmi.version='1.2' timestamp='Thu Mar 26 11:55:39 CET 2015' xmlns:UML='omg.org/UML/2.0' >
<UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
<UML:Package xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427365805826_580042_22' name='migration'>
</UML:Package>
<UML:Package xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427365805826_580042_22' name='migration'>
<UML:Class xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367042666_255023_151' name='Employee'>
</UML:Class>
</UML:Package>
</UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
</XMI>
```

and my xsl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:UML="href://org.omg/UML/1.4" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"   version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="XMI">
<XMI>
    <xsl:attribute name="xmi.version">2.1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="timestamp">
                    <xsl:value-of select='XMI/@timestamp'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
<xsl:template match="UML:Namespace.ownedElement">
<xsl:for-each select="UML:Package">
<packagedElement>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:package</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi.id">
                     <xsl:value-of select='../../@xmi.id'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                     <xsl:value-of select='@name'/>
            </xsl:attribute>


<packagedElement>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Class</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi.id">
                     <xsl:value-of select='@xmi.id'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                     <xsl:value-of select='@name'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
 </packagedElement>
 </packagedElement>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</XMI>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the result I'm getting :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMI xmi.version="2.1" timestamp="" xmlns:UML="org.omg/UML/1.4"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT does have a `<xsl:template../>` inside of another . This does not work. And your second problem is that the xmlns:UML has not two different namespaces in your XML and in your XSLT `omg.org/UML/2.0` and `href://org.omg/UML/1.4`.

Correct this and then it works. Here my XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="XMI">
        <XMI>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi.version">2.1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="timestamp">
                <xsl:value-of select='XMI/@timestamp'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/UML:Package">
                <packagedElement>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:package</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xmi.id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='../../@xmi.id'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select='@name'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>                    

                    <packagedElement>
                        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Class</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="xmi.id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='@xmi.id'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select='@name'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </packagedElement>
                </packagedElement>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </XMI>
    </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Giving this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMI xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML/2.0"
    xmlns:xmi="...omg.org/XMI"
    xmi.version="2.1"
    timestamp="">
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:package" xmi.id="" name="migration">
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class"
            xmi.id="_9_0_bc102e5_1427365805826_580042_22"
            name="migration"/>
    </packagedElement>
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:package" xmi.id="" name="migration">
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class"
            xmi.id="_9_0_bc102e5_1427365805826_580042_22"
            name="migration"/>
    </packagedElement>
</XMI>
```

Comment: "Your XSLT does have a inside of another " what do you mean by this ?

Comment: You have a `<xsl:template../>` inside of your first `<xsl:template`.

Comment: Just remove the `<xsl:template match="UML:Namespace.ownedElement">` just before the for-each. See my code

Comment: I did the changes but still having the same problem

Comment: Ceck your namespace declarations (you need the xmlns:UML and xmlns:xmi declaration), FiveO pointed this issue too.

Comment: Here's the tag where I've putted the xmlns:UML and xmlns:xmi declarations :
'<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:UML="href://org.omg/UML/1.4" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"   version="1.0">'

Comment: This is the output that I get when running
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XMI xmi.version="2.1" timestamp="Thu Mar 26 11:55:39 CET 2015" xmlns:UML="org.omg/UML/1.4" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>'

Comment: Please edit your question for better understanding of your problem - difficult to tell from your comments with the included code.

Comment: @EricS said that I may have a problem with the xmlns:UML and xmlns:xmi declaration so I just copied the tags where they are declared ( you may find them above on the shared code) .
Can this problem be linked to the XSLT environement on eclipse ?